# get the state and more accurate city of a visitor

Tags: php, api, location

I want to know the state and city of my visitors and have this code

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
echo $query['isp'].', '.$query ['country'].', '.$query['city'];
```

Testing on my own visit I get the city 150 km far from my real city.
Is there a way to get more accurate location?

Comment: You can use HTML5 Geolocation, but note the browser will prompt the user for permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Maxmind GeoIP database. https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo. They provide a free version of their database called GeoIp Lite.